# change container view size when embedded page controller reaches index

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

i have a container view that has an embedded page controller within it.

when the page controller index reaches a certain index i want to change the container view size.  The problem is that i can't create an outlet to the container view inside the page controller class and am unsure how to get the changes in index from another class.

i was thinking something like: from page controller class

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if (completed && finished) {
        if let currentVC = pageViewController.viewControllers?.last {
            let index = vcArr.index(of: currentVC)

                globalPageIndex = index!

        }
    }
}
```

where globalPageIndex is declared at the top level.

then in the class that contains reference to container view:

```
if globalPageIndex == 10 {

    containerView?.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.5, 1.5)

}
```

but how can i have the function in this class continuously test for the index value?  if i create a class func in the container view class and run it each time the index is changed from the page controller then i can't access the container view.

-------EDIT------

```
class pageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, ContainerViewDelegate {

internal func getIndex(index: Int) {
    globalIndex = index
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if (completed && finished) {
        if let currentVC = pageViewController.viewControllers?.last {
            let index = vcArr.index(of: currentVC)

            getIndex(index: index!)


        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    LandingPageViewController.delegate = self
```

and in the landingPage

```
protocol ContainerViewDelegate {
    func getIndex(index: Int)
}
class LandingPageViewController: UIViewController {

static var delegate : ContainerViewDelegate!
```

Answer (score 0):

In the pageViewController, within the delegate method, you can send a message to the container view controller. In this way, every time the page view controller transit, the container view controller will receive a message.
In this message, you can pass the index.

Or you can set the container view controller as the delegate of the pageviewcontroller

Comment: i was playing with setting the container as the delegate but its getting complicate.  what do you mean by send a message?  using notification centre or such?

Comment: @Pippo Just like how delegate works. In the pageviewcontroller, keep a reference to the container view controller. Create a public method for the container view controller. In the pageviewcontroller, call this method wherever you want(in this case, should be in the pageviewcontrollerdelegate method). Since you hold a reference to the containerviewcontroller, you know whom to send to message to.

Comment: Thanks for trying to explain.  I'm just very confused with how to use delegate to send message to other class.  i edit question to show i have set landingpage delegate to self. but how to get this value in landing page?